# jquery autocomplete add class name list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add a class to each variable that gets found. As you can see, in the label, the variable 'airport name' will have one class, and 'country' will have another class. So, after, I can apply CSS.

any advice how can this be done

```js
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: "airportinfoWeb.xml",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function (xmlResponse) {
    var data = $("Airport", xmlResponse).map(function () {
      return {
        label: $.trim($("AirportName", this).text()) + ", " + $("Country", this).text(),
        AirportCode: $.trim($("AirportCode", this).text()),
        AirportName: $.trim($("AirportName", this).text()),
        Country: $.trim($("Country", this).text())
      };
    }).get();

    $("#id_AirportCode").autocomplete({
      source: function (req, response) {
        var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
        response($.grep(data, function (item) {
          return matcher.test(item.AirportCode) || matcher.test(item.AirportName) || matcher.test(item.Country);
        }));
      },
      position: {
        my: "left+0 top+4"
      }
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
      // Create a custom item display
      var $li = $("<li></li>")
        .append("<div>" + item.label + "</div>")
        .appendTo(ul);
      return $li;
    };
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is a Javascript question. The Java tag is incorrect. Javascript and Java are completely different languages. Please remove the Java tag.

Comment: the xml used in the code is lacking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add specific classes to each part of the label (e.g., the 'Airport Name' and 'Country'), you can modify the _renderItem function. Specifically, you can wrap each variable in its own HTML element and assign it a class.

Try this:

```
_renderItem: function (ul, item) {
  // Create an element to hold the complete label, composed of different parts
  const completeLabel = $("<div></div>")
  
  // Extract airport name and country from the label
  const airportName = $("<span></span>").addClass('airport-name').text(item.AirportName)
  const country = $("<span></span>").addClass('country').text(item.Country)
  
  // Combine them into the complete label
  completeLabel.append(airportName).append(", ").append(country)
  
  return $("<li></li>")
    .data("value", item)
    .append($("<a></a>").append(completeLabel)) // Add the complete label inside the <a> tag
    .appendTo(ul)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I tried still not working I think my _renderItem function is not getting called. if any
 advice on where I went wrong, , I have updated new code